# b-card-img-lazy not firing error event on image not found

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a `b-card-img-lazy`, as the title suggests, but it does not fire the `load` event when the image is fully "downloaded" nor the `error` event if the resource is not found.
If the image is found, then it is displayed correctly. The only things that are not working are the events to be fired.

I'm using Vue.js 2.0 and Nuxt.js, but this should be an useless information, since a common `img` or `b-img` fire those events as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an external help, [on this issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4424#issuecomment-558364302) on bootstrap-vue GitHub's page I found that the event should be `native`, i.e. I must use `@error.native=".."`.